# What would happen if the image size of training dataset is smaller than Object Detection Neural Network input image size?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, yolov5

The scenario is i want to train a object detection model based on yolov5, the default input image size of yolov5 is 640×640, but my dataset have some images whose image size is less than 640 pixels, what consequen such kind of training dataset would cause ?
[image: yolov5 train.py]

Comment: Images get resized to the given img-size, where some information may be lost if they aren't the correct aspect ratio. In general, try to give images that are bigger than this img size. Smaller images get scaled up, so if you're trying to detect bananas they may get weird sizes and distorted looks.

Comment: Hi, @cbolwerk, you know, there are many kinds of image size processing with the combination of keep aspect ratio, crop, keep width, keep height and padding, so generally what kind of image process the network uses ? Or the network just scale up/down the image without keeping aspect ratio ?

Comment: Please look for this yourself, I'm not really familiar with this yolov5 library either

Comment: @cbolwerk, Hi, i think i got my expected answer from [here](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/800#issuecomment-609566695) for yolov4 and [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/issues/232) for yolov5